# Data frame column with conditional data - Python

Tags: python, numpy, dataframe, pandas

I have some percentages in a data frame column

```
pc
0.32
0.45
0.49
0.60
0.68
0.87
```

And i want to end up with something like this

```
pc     group
0.32    1
0.45    2
0.49    2
0.60    2
0.68    3
0.87    3
```

I've tried

```
df["group"]=3

if df["pc"]<0.66:
    df["group"]=2

elif df["pc"]<0.33:
    df["group"]=1
```

but all i get is

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
df["group"][df["pc"] < 0.66] = 2
df["group"][df["pc"] < 0.33] = 1
```